# How to rotate bones in UE4 with C++?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I just want to create a node that simply specifies the bone name of the character and rotates it.

I want to move multiple bones, not just one bone, using the naming method.

I wrote the following codes.

**MyCharacter.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "GameFramework/Character.h"
#include "MyCharacter.generated.h"
class USkeletalMeshComponent;
class UPoseableMeshComponent;

UCLASS()
class TESTPLUGIN_API AMyCharacter : public ACharacter
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:
    // Sets default values for this character's properties
    AMyCharacter();
    FRotator RotationValue;

protected:
    // Called when the game starts or when spawned
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;

public: 
    // Called every frame
    virtual void Tick(float DeltaTime) override;

    // Called to bind functionality to input
    virtual void SetupPlayerInputComponent(class UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent) override;

private:
    UPoseableMeshComponent* PoseableMesh;
};
```

**MyCharacter.cpp**

```
#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "GameFramework/Character.h"
#include "MyCharacter.generated.h"
class USkeletalMeshComponent;
class UPoseableMeshComponent;

UCLASS()
class TESTPLUGIN_API AMyCharacter : public ACharacter
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:
    // Sets default values for this character's properties
    AMyCharacter();
    FRotator RotationValue;

protected:
    // Called when the game starts or when spawned
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;

public: 
    // Called every frame
    virtual void Tick(float DeltaTime) override;

    // Called to bind functionality to input
    virtual void SetupPlayerInputComponent(class UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent) override;

private:
    UPoseableMeshComponent* PoseableMesh;
};
```

When I compile the above code and open it with a level blueprint, I see a node like the one in the figure below.

[image]

This node is not what I wanted.

I want to create a node that can connect to FinalAnimationPose as shown in the image below.

[image]

How can I create a node like this?

All I want to do is simply rotate the bones every second. I couldn't find this information.

I am a beginner in both UE4 and C ++. Any answer will help.

Comment: Please consider joining to https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I am new to UE but I think it was the same question which was asked in UE community to rotate but it was for a single bone:

Here's the link to that: https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/47930/how-to-rotate-bone-in-c.html

Comment: I also saw that page. However, even though my code uses the SetBoneRotationByName function as in that example, my code doesn't show a human-shaped connection to connect to the FinalAnimationPose....